# Reset my app on Fortrabbit

Tags: fortrabbit

I created app on Fortrabbit and purchased a service for my app. I pushed some my app (Laravel) and created my database. Now I want to reset my app. How can I do that? Could somebody help?

Comment: Do you want to start with a new git repository or a new database ?

Comment: @edi9999 new database. actually I want to reset my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from Fortrabbit Support:

```
sorry, it's not possible to reset the git repo (for now).
But you can push new code any time. You can also delete files when you ssh into you App.


If you want to start form the scratch, I suggest to spin up a new App.
```

Comment: Or just contact us an we reset the repo for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I use myself using laravel 4 to flush a complete DB in Fortrabbit

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
$tables= DB::select('SHOW TABLES;');
foreach ($tables as $table) { 
  foreach ($table as $key=>$tableName) {
    $tables= DB::statement("DROP TABLE $tableName;");
  }
}
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
```